# Firestore Write Limits in Subcollections with CollectionGroupQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Following up on my previous post learning about write limits to individual collections

[Firestore 500+ Writes Per Second to One Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818648/firestore-500-writes-per-second-to-one-collection)

How does this 500ps limit apply to **CollectionGroups** that were recently introduced? (btw...[Todd didn't get a loud enough cheer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW7DWV2jST0&feature=youtu.be&t=1569&linkId=69019935)! :P)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Firestore limits still only reference individual collections:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

> Maximum write rate to a ***collection*** in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field:    **500 per second**

Dan McGrath in my previous post said this is because indexing for **Individual** `Collections`

> will be limited by the load a **single server can handle**.

Example data model:

- **Collection**: users
- **Doc**: userId1
- **Subcollection**: posts
- **Doc**: postId1  (fields for postId, img, caption, date)

If I create a `CollectionGroup` Index for `posts` (query across all subcollections called "posts") -
order **DESCENDING** by `date`

**Would my write limit across all those subcollections go down from 10k per second to 500 per second? How is CollectionGroup indexing handled? By the same "individual server"?**

If so...this essentially means theres no benefit to putting these "posts" in separate subcollections vs. one individual root level collection **from a write limit perspective.**

Comment: Any insights here Firebase team????

Answer (score 1):

Asked on Firebase Google Group - answer is yes, **you are limited to 500 writes per second across subcollections if you start indexing them using CollectionGroupQuery**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/7Raajf8KWg4

> As with many limitations of Cloud Firestore, this limit is based on our ability to index data and maintain strong consistency.  So yes: if you have a CollectionGroup index on "date" and your date field has sequential values, you should not exceed 500QPS write rate for updates for "posts" documents.

Comment: Strange thing is my sub collection does not have any indexes but reaching max write now.